# PHP Stream Wrapper Meta Data

Tags: php, stream, stream-wrapper

`Hello, world!`

I need to be able to pass information from a custom stream wrapper to the code using it, but I've been having some trouble with it.  The best option seemed to use `stream_get_meta_data()`, but I haven't been able to find a method in the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.streamwrapper.php) that allows me to set the wrapper-specific `wrapper_data` data.

What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: Maybe check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734592/using-a-custom-stream-wrapper-as-test-stub-for-phps-http-stream-wrapper ?

Comment: did you have any luck?

Comment: Sorry @guruz, I'm not sure, I don't even remember what the question was even about :'(